# Requirements for KDF and randomness extractor

Tags: hash, key-derivation

What requirements KDF and randomness extractor does not have to meet, but the the hash function have to meet? I suspect that using hash functions as KDFs and randomness extractors is enough, but in some aspects more than we need.

If we consider some weak, biased source of entropy it looks like randomness extractor:

- doesn't have to be irreversible,
- doesn't have to have so big state/output (at least 256-bits), but I'm not sure,
- doesn't have to have key, but this may be option.

And if we consider some weak, biased source of entropy and KDF:

- does it have to be irreversible? If we are not talking about PBKDF feeded by known salt and password, but KDF for key derivation from source of entropy, keys are secrets anyway - there will be no way to try to reverse them, so it seems like in this case KDF don't have to be irreversible; but in case of PBKDF is could be irreversible,
- does it have to have so big state/output (at least 256-bits)? Here again in case of source of entropy it seems to me like it doesn't have to, and in case of PBKDF, because of salt it also seems to like it doesn't have to have so big output,
- key may be useful or nedeed.

Comment: But derivation of they key can be done without password, just from some entropy source, isn't it?

Comment: Use entropy source instead of using password.

Comment: @PaulUszak randomness extractor output is non deterministic? I didn't know that. For now I have no intention to achieve something. It just looks like to me, that hash functions are more than we need to extract randomness. If this is true, maybe we may create something more efficient to extract randomness from entropy source. Maybe some randomness extractors or KDF not based on hash functions, but still secure enough.

Comment: Randomness extractors tend to be hash based, but don't have to be. All that you have to do is squish the input distribution into a uniform distribution. Any means will do, invertible or not, e.g. von Neumann or sequential XOR. I extract from JPEGs using a [fold and sum](http://www.reallyreallyrandom.com/photonic/technical/entropy-measurement-2/) technique I thought up in the bath.